# Every nilpotent ideal is a nil ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. An ideal $I$ of $R$ is called nilpotent if $I^{n} = {0}$ for some positive integer $n$. I want to show that every nilpotent ideal is a nil ideal.

Please help me.... i can't start with the proof.

Comment: It seems to me like you only need to apply the definitions. Why can't you start with the proof?

Answer (score 6):

An ideal $J$ is called *nil* if every element $t \in J$ is nilpotent; that is, if every $ t \in J$ satisfies $t^m = 0$ for some $m \in \Bbb N$ (and here I take $0 \ne \Bbb N$).  Recall the the definition of of $J_1 J_2$ for ideals $J_1$ and $J_2$ is

$J_1 J_2 = \{\sum j_{1i} j_{2i} \mid j_{1i} \in J_1; j_{2i} \in J_2 \}; \tag{1}$

here it is of course understood that that sums occurring in (1) are finite.  It is easy to see from this definition that $j^2 \in J^2$ for $j \in J$, and if $j^k \in J^k$ for $k \in \Bbb N$ then clearly $j^{k + 1} = jj^k \in J^{k + 1}$; thus it follows by induction that $j^m \in J^m$ for all $m \in \Bbb N$.  Now if $i \in I$ and $I^n = 0$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$, we have $i^n = 0$ as well since as has just been shown $i^n \in I^n$; every $i \in I$ is nilpotent; this shows that $I$ is, in fact, a nil ideal.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  May the New Year Bode Well,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***